# empty tableview from loading data from json in swift 4

Tags: json, swift, swift4

so yea thank you guys, i've just changed the whole codes to codeable to proper swift 4 lol. but the tableview still isnt shown n the console says:
"downloaded
something is wrong when downloaded"

```
final let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=espn&apiKey=ada86a1d56d348a29a7c7501869bac2f")
private var articles = [Article]()
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadJson()
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
    }

func downloadJson(){
            guard let downloadURL = url else {return}
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL){data, URLResponse, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil, URLResponse != nil else{
                    print("something is wrong")
                    return
                }
                print("downloaded")
                do
                {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let downloadedArticles = try decoder.decode(Articles.self, from: data)
                    self.articles = downloadedArticles.articles
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }catch {
                    print("something is wrong when downloaded")
                }
            }.resume()
        }
```

and this is from the article codable class

```
class Articles: Codable {
    let articles: [Article]

    init(articles: [Article]){
        self.articles = articles
    }
}

class Article: Codable{
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let author: String
    let image: String

    init(title: String, description: String, author: String, image: String){
        self.title = title
        self.description = description
        self.author = author
        self.image = image
        }
}
```

and here is the cellforrowat (i cant posted it because my whole post mostly the codes. lol):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArticleCell") as? ArticleCell else {
            return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.titleLabel.text = "" + articles[indexPath.row].title
        cell.descLabel.text = "" + articles[indexPath.row].description
        cell.authorLabel.text = "" + articles[indexPath.row].author

        if let imageURL = URL(string: articles[indexPath.row].image){
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                if let data = data {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.imgView.image = image
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: At some point, you need to debug. Is `article.author = author` called? When you call `self.tableview.reloadData()`, is `articles` empty?

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that `datasource` (and also `delegate` for future use) of the table view is connected in Interface Builder.

For a table view it's `indexPath.row` rather than `indexPath.item`.

Further it's recommended to get the data source item only once in `cellForRow` and declare the data source array as non-optional (The tutorial is quite poor suggesting bad habits and half knowledge). And – as always – the option `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift.

```
var articles = [Article]()
```

---

```
     if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String:Any],
        let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        ...
```

---

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell

    let article = articles[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = article.headline
    cell.desc.text = article.desc
    cell.author.text = article.author
    cell.imgView.downloadImage(from: article.imageUrl!)!
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return articles.count
}
```

Delete the `numberOfSections` method. The default is `1`.

And in Swift 3+ a JSON dictionary is `[String : Any]`, not `[String : AnyObject]`

---

In Swift 4 consider to use the `Codable` protocol to parse the JSON into a struct. It's much more convenient.

---

**Update:**

The class `Article` doesn't match the JSON at the given URL. Change it to the following. `author` must be optional and there is no key `image`. By the way, if you are adopt `Codable` you don't need to write initializers.

```
class Articles: Codable {
    let articles: [Article]
}

class Article: Codable {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    let author: String?
    let urlToImage: URL
}
```

PS: `URLResponse` is a type. Use something lowercased to avoid confusion for example `dataTask(with: downloadURL) {data, response, error`. But in your case the parameter is not needed at all.

Comment: i've changed it to codable class but still wont worked hahah. mind if u check? :)

Comment: ah sorry, i've mistakenly paste my reference codes instead lol. ive been changed it to matched my project codes and add cellforrowat :)

Comment: I updated the answer again. The decoding is supposed to work.

Comment: ive been followed ur instruction for the Article class. but how do you call optional string and url in cellForRowAt? i tried a few times. but seems i messed up so much this time lol.

Comment: The syntax `"" + articles[indexPath.row].author` is ridiculous. In the `cellForRow` method – which I stroke through – I showed you the right way to assign string values to a label. Regarding the image: First of all the URL is not optional but your way is completely wrong anyway. **Never** use `Data(contentsOf:` to load data from a remote URL and consider that the cell can be deallocated immediately when the user scrolls. You have to use a separate download manager providing a cache for the image.

Answer (score 0):

You should check in debug what with your json and articlesFromJs.
Maybe articlesFromJs is empty or format of JSON is incorrect.

> let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String : AnyObject]

and

> if let articlesFromJson = json["articles"] as? [[String : >AnyObject]]

Also use Codable instead of JSONSerialization.

Comment: i've changed it to codable class but still wont worked hahah. mind if u check? :)

Comment: Can you show your json file and how do you convert it?